# AJAX не вызывает функцию

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть представление с вкладками:

**Select.cshtml**

```html
<body>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" id="class1">
            <a href="#tab_1_1" class="tbs" data-info="class1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                1 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class2">
            <a href="#tab_1_2" class="tbs" data-info="class2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                2 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class3">
            <a href="#tab_1_3" class="tbs" data-info="class3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                3 класс
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('.tbs').on('click', function () {        
        var info = $(this).data('info');
        switch (info) {
            case 'class2':
                $('#tab_1_2').load("/Work201615/Class2"); //Controller method which returns partial view             
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Work201615Controller.cs**

```
public class Work201615Controller : Controller
{
    // GET: Work201615
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Class2()
    {
        return PartialView("_PartialClass2");
    }
}
```

При выборе вкладки `2 класс` должен вызываться метод `Class2()` из контроллера `Work201615`. Но этого не происходит. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: смотрите ошибки в консоли.

Comment: @Grundy если речь идет о консоли браузера, то там пусто - никакой реакции.

Comment: а, ну логично :) я что-то не вижу в разметке элемента с `id="tab_1_2"`

Comment: Ну и не совсем уверен что тег `<script>` помещенный _после_ body - отработает. Обычно его помещают _перед закрывающим тегом body_

Comment: href="#tab_1_2"  заменить на id="#tab_1_2" , если анкор не нужен, если нужен - просто добавьте id="#tab_1_2"  к нужному элементу

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́, если указать в разметке в id значение начинающееся с `#` его потом просто так не выбрать селектором jQuery :)

Comment: @Grundy, блин, точно, накопипастил, спасибо за замечание :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашей разметке нет элемента с id="tab_1_2". Следовательно селектор `$('#tab_1_2')` вернет пустую коллекцию. В случае пустой коллекции запрос даже не будет послан, так как его результат все равно некуда вставлять.

Чтобы пример заработал необходимо добавить в разметку элемент в который будут загружаться данные. А так же возможно стоит внести тег script внутрь тега body

```
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        ...
        <li class="" id="class2">
            <a href="#tab_1_2" class="tbs" data-info="class2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                2 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    ...
    <div id="tab_1_2"></div>
    <script>
        $('.tbs').on('click', function () {...});
    </script>
</body>
```